# Passing Data Through ViewControllers Not Working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, message-passing

Ok so I am trying to pass data from one view controller to another via the following code but its not working and I have no idea why.

In my ViewController.m I have imported ViewControllerTwo.h and declared ViewControllerTwo:

```
    #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "ViewControllerTwo.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController
    {
        ViewControllerTwo *settings;

    }
    @synthesize blockSizeLB;
    @synthesize wpmLB;
    @synthesize textTV;
    @synthesize slider;
    @synthesize stepper;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //sets label to corresponding value
    wpmLB.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"WPM: %@", [[NSNumber numberWithInt:slider.value] stringValue]];

    //configure stepper and its label to default values of 1
    stepper.value = 1;
    blockSizeLB.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Block Size: %@", [[NSNumber numberWithInt:stepper.value] stringValue]];

     //sets properties for next ViewController
    settings = [[ViewControllerTwo alloc] init];
    settings.timerValue = 60 / slider.value;
    settings.text = textTV.text;
    settings.blockCount = stepper.value;



}
```

In ViewControllerTwo.h I have:

```
@property (nonatomic) float timerValue;
@property (nonatomic) NSString * text;
@property (nonatomic) int blockCount;
```

Later on in the ViewController.m I need to change the properties defined in ViewControllerTwo:
Method from ViewController.m. This is also done earlier in my viewDidLoad to set the default values of the properties:

```
- (IBAction)sliderSlide:(id)sender
{
    //event when the slider value is changed


    //rounds value to nearest increment of 5
    int increment = 5 * floor(((int)slider.value/5)+0.5);
    [slider setValue:increment animated:YES];

    //changes WPM: 0 label text
    wpmLB.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"WPM: %@", [[NSNumber numberWithInt:increment] stringValue]];

  //sets properties for next ViewController   
    settings.timerValue = 60 / slider.value;   
}
```

I try to test if this is successful by calling a method in ViewControllerTwo.m that logs its property blockCount via NSLog. The output however is (null) meaning I was unsuccesful in passing the data from ViewController.m to ViewControllerTwo

Comment: Where do you initialize the `settings` variable to point to an actual `ViewControllerTwo` object?

Comment: I updated it to include my viewDidLoad method where I put it. Could it because Im setting values to a property before it is synthesized in the ViewControllerTwo.m?

Comment: I'm suspicious whether or not the instance of `ViewControllerTwo` that you create as `settings` is the same one you're testing.  If you log the value of `settings` when you assign values to it and the value of `self` when `ViewControllerTwo` prints its `blockCount`, do they show the same address?

Comment: They do not. In my ViewController.m the address of settings.text is: 2015-01-11 17:30:24.213 Spreed[7688:157905] 0x7f92a2435260.    In my ViewControllerTwo the address for self.text is 2015-01-11 17:30:26.603 Spreed[7688:157905] 0x0. How do I make sure that my instance in ViewController refers to the ViewControllerTwo I made in storyboard?

Comment: Are you using a segue?

Comment: I have a button on ViewController that segues to ViewControllerTwo but Both are inside a navigation controller so I need to update data from ViewController to ViewControllerTwo using non segue methods. If I didnt, the user could use the navigation controller to move from viewcontroller to viewcontrollertwo and wrong data could be displayed.

Comment: @user2692560 So the main question what (if any) code are you using to perform the transition between the first and second view controller? Because you need to be performing the transition using the particular ViewControllerTwo instance you already created.

Comment: I am using storyboard ctrl + click and drag to transition from a button on first view controller to push the second view controller. So im not using any code per say

Comment: That's called a segue.

Comment: I thought you meant programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using segues, you should be doing this inside of:
`- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`
Then name your segue, then do something like this:

```
if([segue.identifier  isEqual: @"segue_From_1_To_2"])
{
    ViewControllerTwo *vc2 = segue.destinationViewController;
    vc2.timerValue = 123.45;
    vc2.text = @"whatever";
    vc2.blockCount = 1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom initializer in your viewControllerTwo. name it initWithTimerValue:

```
- (id)initWithTimerValue:(CGFloat)timerValue
{

self = [super init];
if (self) {
self.timerValue = timerValue;
}

return self;

}
```